# htaccess RewriteCond to redirect public and private/admin queries

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm attempting to rewrite incoming URIs directed at my custom admin system through an existing .htaccess file which already maintains rewrites for the public side of my site.

Problem is no matter what I do, both RewriteRule's keep getting executed. Here's the code I'm currently working with.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myadmin/
RewriteRule ^(([a-z]{2})(-[a-z]{2})?)(/([a-z0-9-\./]*))?$ /index.php?lng=$1&tpl=$4 [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/myadmin/
RewriteRule ^myadmin/(([a-z]{2})(-[a-z]{2})?)(/([a-z0-9-\./]*))?$ /myadmin/index.php?vlng=$1&tpl=$4 [QSA,L,NC]
```

If I call

> abc.com/myadmin/

the cookies that I only update for the public side of my side are being updated, I just can't seem to stop the first condition from running when I'm trying to access the URI for my admin area.

Can anyone advise me on a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the problem, it was partly my fault for assuming the **Clear Cache extension in my Chrome browser** only worked on a single tab at a time and a default setting in that extension that **automatically reload all tabs after the extension was activated**.

Like most developers I have between 5-10 tabs open in my browser at any given moment while developing to access testing areas of my site, development tools and technical resources.  When I work on code I generally do all my cache cleaning by hand personally so that I know it is really done, in this case I chose to add a new extension to my Chrome browser called 'Clear Cache' to help me take care of this a little faster because I was making a lot of small changes which I needed to make clean tests of each time.  What I didn't realise was that when you activate the extension it also cleans the cache of all your other tabs as well.  I also didn't notice the default setting that is set to automatically reload them all after the cleaning is performed.  Because it also doesn't show you that it is reloading all these other tabs visually I had no idea it was reloading a tab that I had open to the main page of the site I was working on that was responsible for loading cookies.

To summarize while I worked on my site, in one tab, testing changes to my admin area I kept seeing cookie updates that could only come from the public side of my site and it kept making me think there was something still wrong with my htaccess changes.  I realized, after two days of troubleshooting, the handy dandy extension I'd added to help make things easier was actually reloading all the tabs in my browser without letting me know and all those other calls were responsible for the continual return of cookies that could only be generated by the public side of my site which was confusing the hell out of me.  I'll be going to go back to clearing my cache by hand again after this.